# Effect of upgrading windows server 2012 data center

Tags: sql-server, replication, windows

I have a production `windows server 2012 data center` server where IIS and SQL server was installed and replication was configured in SQL Server. It is infected with a malware. After cleaning it with an anti malware, I am unable to install applications `(MSI installer problem).`
I have tried almost every option available but no joy - I still can't install applications.

Finally I have decided to upgrade/repair the OS.

Will it affect the SQL sever replication, The IIS configuration? any Idea?

Comment: My recommendation would be to copy the data from the server to somewhere safe, wipe the server disk clean, reinstall the OS, reinstall your anti malware software, then finally reinstall your applications.

Comment: I agree with Gilbert, wipe the server totally. Can you be sure that's the only server that has been affected?

Comment: Currently it is clean of malware but the malware has already affected some system/registry files which wouldn't let me install other applications. The reason I don't want to go with the format is, the reconfiguration of replication and setting up of the website will for sure take time since it is a production server. If I go with the repair, will it affect the database server as well as the IIS?

Comment: Replication setup/tear down is as simple as TSQL scripts.  Simply script out your replication setup using the wizards, once you rebuild your server, then re-apply your TSQL scripts.